# Why __gcd() is throwing error in macOS mojave?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++, clang++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
   
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> a[i];

    int ans = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
       ans = __gcd(ans, a[i]);

    cout << ans << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is throwing the following error:

error: static_assert failed due to requirement '!is_signed::value'

note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__gcd' requested here
ans = __gcd(ans, a[i]);

I am using command g++ -std=c++17 which worked for every program except this one.

This code is working without error on code.hackerearth.com online compiler which uses g++ 5.4.0

EDIT: Removed bits/stdc++.h header and included required headers only.

After removing also the same problem is happening.

The SAME code is running properly in online ide. Link of one such ide is [ONLINE IDE](https://code.hackerearth.com/429f68D)

Using their c++ compiler and function __gcd(a, b) doesn't give any error but, when I change it to gcd(a, b) in the same ide, it does give error that this function definition is not found.

When I run the same code in my local machine, everything happens in just the opposite way. __gcd(a, b) doesn't work while gcd(a, b) works.

Comment: __gcd is private, don't use it... What is not clear in the error message? It only works with unsigned types.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? g++ or clang++?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @vivek: that is unfortunate. Still no excuse to use a implementation-private function

Comment: @vivek: the implementation-private part refers to __gcd. Double underscores signify nonstandard functions for implementation-internal use. The header was another problem

Comment: @MSalters Thanks! I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `bit/C++.h`, it's a private header.

Use proper C++ functions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd

They support signed integers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> a(n);

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cin >> a[i];

int ans = a[0];
for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
   ans = gcd(ans, a[i]);

cout << ans << endl;

return 0;
}
```

works with `clang++ -std=c++17`.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Besides, the function is from c++17 only.

Comment: Which is available on Mojave.

Comment: This code is working without error on code.hackerearth.com online compiler which uses g++ 5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    if (b == 0)
       return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b); 
}
```

As in my mac '__gcd()' is also not working and showing that "use of undeclared identifier' so I have to predefine this function.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says, use the standard `std::gcd` instead of a non-standard `__gcd`, if possible.

That said, the error means that `__gcd` only works on unsigned integers. Change the types of your variables from `int` to `unsigned int`.